# Is there a way in the Jenkins Pipeline to change 'almost complete' verbiage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to change the 'almost complete' along the way to give real information to the users.  Is there a way to change that similar to the changing of the build name? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Corresponding to this ticket [JENKINS-39188](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39188), i think there is actually no way to change this progress bar , because the behavior of the bar is hard coded in this [.hbs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/blob/master/ui/src/main/js/view/templates/pipeline-staged.hbs) file.

In the normal behavior the bar should show you the time. This is actually not working, but they are working on a fix [JENKINS-38536](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38536).